# How to use environment variable values to access cloudinary API in java?

Tags: java, gradle, environment-variables, cloudinary

I have a requirement of uploading images to `cloudinary` using cloudinary's java API.I have created cloudinary account through which i got api `Cloud name`,`API Key`,`API Secret`. Using these things i am able to upload my images to cloudinary like bellow:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadPic")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile){

        String cloudinaryImgURL=null;
        try {

            File fileDir = new File("rowFiles");
            if (! fileDir.exists()){
                fileDir.mkdir();

            }
            String fileName=multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            File physicalFile=new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(fileDir.getName()+"/"+physicalFile);
            fout.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
            fout.close();

            //For stack-overflow question using dummy values for credientials.
            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
                      "cloud_name", "your_cloud_name",
                      "api_key", "your_api_key",
                      "api_secret", "your_secret_key"));



            File toUpload = new File("rowFiles/"+fileName);
            Map params = ObjectUtils.asMap("public_id", "SRWRestImageBase/"+fileName);

            Map uploadResult =Singleton.getCloudinary().uploader().upload(toUpload, params);
            toUpload.delete();
            System.out.println("==============>>"+uploadResult.get("url"));
            cloudinaryImgURL=uploadResult.get("url").toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("upload:"+e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("File uploaded successfully:"+cloudinaryImgURL,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But now my problem is that i keep this code in public git repo, and from there i push this code to `Heroku`. But using this method will expose my `cloudinary` details like `Cloud name`,`API Key`,`API Secret` to everyone which i don't want.

Looking at cloudinary's documentation for [getting started](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_integration#overview)  i found the way of using environment variable to store these values and access it from there, but document doesn't guide me properly.

I have used 
In a Java EE environment you can set an environment variable available to your Java EE container:

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://{api_key}:{api_secret}@{cloud_name}
```

This will enable you to receive a Cloudinary instance:

```
Cloudinary cloudinary = Singleton.getCloudinary();
```

But i am getting compile-time error for class `Singleton` that it is not able to find in any jar. Looking at some other article, this class should `com.cloudinary.Singleton`, but my cloudinary jar does not have this class.

I am using cloudinary gradle dependancy as:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudinary/cloudinary-http43
compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-http43', version: '1.2.2'
```

It would be appreciated if someone can guide me in right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also depend on `cloudinary-taglib`. See [the `Singleton` class on github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/blob/master/cloudinary-taglib/src/main/java/com/cloudinary/Singleton.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own solution. 
We have to set environment variable `CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://{api_key}:{api_secret}@{cloud_name}` and restart eclipse to reflect the environment variable changes and following changes. This way it wont expose my account details to public repo.

```
@PostMapping("/uploadPic")
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile){
    String cloudinaryImgURL=null;
    try {
        File fileDir = new File("rowFiles");
        if (! fileDir.exists()){
            fileDir.mkdir();
        }
        String fileName=multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        File physicalFile=new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(fileDir.getName()+"/"+physicalFile);
        fout.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        fout.close();
        File toUpload = new File("rowFiles/"+fileName);
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary();
        System.out.println("API Key:"+cloudinary.config.apiKey);
        Map params = ObjectUtils.asMap("public_id", "SRWRestImageBase/"+fileName);
        Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(toUpload, params);
        toUpload.delete();
        System.out.println("==============>>"+uploadResult.get("url"));
        cloudinaryImgURL=uploadResult.get("url").toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("upload:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>("File uploaded successfully:"+cloudinaryImgURL,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```